# difference between lam and paste

Tags: command-line, unix, shell

I don't get the difference between the program lam

> **lam** -- laminate files
>   The lam utility copies the named files side by side onto the standard 
>            output.  The n-th input lines from the input files are considered 
>            fragments of the single long n-th output line into which they are 
>            assembled.  The name `-' means the standard input, and may be repeated.

and paste

> **paste** -- merge corresponding or subsequent lines of files
>   The paste utility concatenates the corresponding lines of the given input 
>        files, replacing all but the last file's newline characters with a single 
>        tab character, and writes the resulting lines to standard output.  If 
>        end-of-file is reached on an input file while other input files still 
>        contain data, the file is treated as if it were an endless source of empty 
>        lines.

Except for the command options. I don't get the difference. Suppose I have two files a and b

```
a
------------
1
2
3

b
------------
4
5
6
```

I get

```
$ paste -d ',' a b
1,4
2,5
3,6

$ lam a -s',' b
1,4
2,5
3,6
```

They seem redundant in scope, although lam seems to be more flexible. The descriptions do not allow me to catch cases where they could behave differently. Does anybody have a clue ?

Comment: They are redundant in scope.  lam was part of BSD, paste AT&T.  paste was later standardized in POSIX.2.  lam hangs around for hysterical reasons. TIMTOWTDI

Comment: @RichardHoskins In my opinion that's good enough to be an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[paste](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/upaste.htm) applies to complete files. Therefore it will concatenate complete files into a single file. Lines will be merge if they are the same.

[lam](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=lam&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current) applies to lines in a file as well as files. Therefore you can selectively concatenate lines into a new file.

Comment: Interesting, I have mostly used `join` for these things. http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_join.htm

Comment: @nik. So do I - Or I just do a copy

Answer (score 1):

With lam you can use delimiters with more than one character.